# Error calling Java function on reusable feature when using parallelization

Tags: java, testing, karate

I'm getting an error (karate version: '1.1.0.RC2') when reusing java function

Java method

```
package utils;

public class Util {
public static String getDateFromToday(int addDaysFromToday) {
    return LocalDate.now().plusDays(addDaysFromToday).toString();
}
}
```

Scenario:

```
Scenario: The scenario that I reused
        * def util = Java.type('utils.Util')
        * def start = util.getDateFromToday(10)
```

When I'm using more than 1 thread I'm getting the following error for random tests during the suite execution:

```
* def start = util.getDateFromToday(10)
>>>> js failed:
01: util.getDateFromToday(10)
<<<<
org.graalvm.polyglot.PolyglotException: TypeError: invokeMember (getDateFromToday) on utils.Util failed due to: Unknown identifier: getDateFromToday
- <js>.:program(Unnamed:1)
```

If I only use 1 thread everything works fine